# Can't access elements in detox after react-native firstly load

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I'm running detox on app that started from native app and now working as a combination of react native app and native code.

I'm using iOS simulator to check the test.

My app is starting in the iOS native side, and the detox tests running on it and get the elements(all works fine), but as we go with the flow of the app, when we firstly load the bundle(index.js- for running the react-native side), we can't access the elements(in the native side) with detox, and the tests failed.

In the native side(iOS) i entered the buttons with - accessibilityIdentifier

```
describe('Previews', () => {

  beforeAll(async () => {
      await device.launchApp({ permissions: {notifications: 'YES',location:'always'}});
    });
   
     it('should tap on acceptButton', async () => {
       await element(by.id('acceptButton')).tap();
     });
   
     it('should tap on enable Notifications button', async () => {
       await element(by.id('enableNotificationsButton')).tap();
     });

     // Here the bundle of the react-native loading, and the detox can't find 'editButton'
     // 'editButton' it's still in the native side
    it('should click on editButton',  async() => {
       await element(by.id('editButton')).toBeVisible();
     });

});
```

Getting this warning:

```
detox[73960] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = 6) invoke: {"type":"action","action":"tap","predicate":{"type":"id","value":"continueFaceIdButton"}}

Unresponded network requests might result in timeout errors in Detox tests.
```